# PyTorch variable copy

Tags: python, pytorch

now I have two encoders, a projector and an MLP as the classifier, input data and ground truth
e.g encoder1 one and encoder2, projector and mlp, data and label

```
data = ... # a tensor
label = ...
encoder1 = ... # nn.Module
encoder2 = ...
prejector = ...
mlp = ...
```

I used two loss functions to calculate the loss, e.g lossfn1, lossfn2

```
lossfn1 = ...
lossfn2 = ...
```

then I ran this code:

```
temp = encoder1(data)
feature1 = projector(temp)
feature2 = encoder2(data)
prediction = mlp(feature2)

loss1 = lossfn1(feature1, feature2)
loss2 = lossfn2(prediction, label)
loss = loss1 + 0.5 * loss2
loss.backward()
```

then the python interpreter will give an error that
`RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [768, 1126]] is at version 1; expected version 0 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).`
if I copy the data, and input it and its copy, then the code could run.
i.e :

```
data_copy = copy.deepcopy(data)
temp = encoder1(data_copy)
feature1 = projector(temp)
feature2 = encoder2(data)
prediction = mlp(feature2)

loss1 = lossfn1(feature1, feature2)
loss2 = lossfn2(prediction, label)
loss = loss1 + 0.5 * loss2
loss.backward()
```

the following is a simple picture of the architecture of this two circumstances:
[no data copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Sr2.jpg)
[data copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTUmS.jpg)

so why there will have different between them?

I used some single architecture modules to substitute the original modules, and the code could run under both circumstances. But when I used the full architecture, there will have errors.